# Get NPM Package README via API

Tags: php, npm, curl

I need to get NPM Package README files in PHP. Does anyone know an API that I can use to grab this?

I've tried to use registry.npmjs.org, although the latest version of packages that I am testing with do not reflect a README file.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you need the content of the README file of a repo. From what I know, currently, <s>NPM registry does not provide this.</s>  FASLE: npm does offer the readme file for SOME packages:

- this has README: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
- this does not altho in the git repo it clearly shows README: https://registry.npmjs.org/react/

A possible workaround would be to use the git repo URL from the NPM response object and fetch the README file using [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-a-repository-readme).

I think you should investigate this further to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: can do it in a couple of steps, for example grabbing express readme, fetch `https://registry.npmjs.org/express` json then decode it and grab the latest version from $result->versions, download the file https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.17.3.tgz, read the readme.md from the compressed file. a lot of packages on npm don't use a vcs like github, when you publish on npm you can directly push the code to npm so the only source of truth is on npm for all packages on npm